# How to change the ext framework folder to a external Url

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following problem.
The "ext" folder of a Ext js framework is very heavy in order to upload it to the repository so we are planning to upload it to our local server and point at it when we build the app.
The problem comes when Sencha cmd cant find the folder when its uploadded externally.
This is my workspace.json:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "ext": {
            // this is the closest i've gotten
            "path":"C:/ext",
            "version":"6.2.0.981"
        }
    },

    "build": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/build"
    },

    "packages": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/packages/local,${workspace.dir}/packages",

        "extract": "${workspace.dir}/packages/remote"
    }
}
```

is there something like : `"path":"localhost/ext"`?

Comment: You can just put it in the .gitignore file and still have it locally in your workspace or if you have "local server" set-up some file sharing system compatible with your OS and put the network path in there. I don't think that you can put http path in there.

Comment: Instead of `C:/ext`, you can use an NFS or SMB drive, if you assign a drive letter to it. I find my copy of the framework in `smb://fileserver/Software/ExtJS/lib/extjs-6.0.2`, and [through GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902(v=ws.11).aspx), that folder is available on `T:\Software\ExtJS\lib\extjs-6.0.2` to every developer.

Comment: You can give path to in your `.sencha\workspace\sencha.cfg` where to replace `ext` directory to path like `ext.dir=${workspace.dir}/../../../../../SharedLibrary/Ext-5.1.1`

Comment: That was it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724186/how-to-change-the-ext-framework-folder-to-a-external-url#comment68701685_40724186 We simply uploaded the whole workspace.